# How to Install VMWare Tools on Ubuntu 9.10 running under VMWare Fusion on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, vmware-fusion

I've chosen the menu item "Install VMWare Tools", and it instructs me that it will attached the CD.

From there, apparently, I need to log into guest and mount the CD Rom, following instructions to install.

But I don't know how to do that!

Best thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that intuitive, unfortunately. It mounts an ISO which you can find in Nautilus. The ISO contains the tarball of the VMware tools. Untar the tarball in a writable folder (e.g. Downloads). I haven't quite figured out how Ubuntu handles mounted volumes, but for me it's in `/media/cdrom1` (I'm typically a Mac user).

```
tar zxf /media/cdrom1/VMwareTools-8.2.4-215242.tar.gz
```

Change to the VMware tools directory.

```
cd vmware-tools-distrib
```

Install the VMware tools from there.

```
sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

Follow the instructions from there. All the default answers to the questions the installer asks apply to Ubuntu. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, this answer seems good so far... just needed to mount the cdrom first with:

sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom

I'll just finish the process and report back

Comment: yep, that worked